# Eventhandling in Java

Tags: java, android, event-handling, calendarview

So I am programming in Android Studio in the language Java, on a very basic level. However I need help with creating some event handling.

I have made a calendar using the function CalendarView as seen below.

And I need to create a function that lets me (upon clicking a date) create an event for that day, and I really don't know how to do that.

Any way that this is possible to do?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
private void initializeCalendar() {
    calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);

    //sets whether to show the week number.
    calendar.setShowWeekNumber(false);

    //sets the first day of the week according to the Calendar.
    //here we set Monday as the first day of the Calendar.
    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(2);

    //The background color for the selected week.
    calendar.setSelectedWeekBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

    //sets the color for the dates of an unfocused month
    calendar.setUnfocusedMonthDateColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

    //sets the color for the seperator line between weeks.
    calendar.setWeekSeparatorLineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

    //sets the color for the vertical bar shwon at the beginning and at the end of the selected date.
    calendar.setSelectedDateVerticalBar(R.color.darkgreen);

    //sets the listener to be notified upon selected date change.
    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: By creating event means creating event in your mobile calendar or in your app?

Comment: Preferably the event should be within the applications calendar, however if this is very hard to do and/or requires a lot of coding, the mobile calendar could be used instead.

Comment: I think the best way would be to save the event in the DB when user create it, and load that date in calendar with different color. Again is the app need to do any thing special on that day? if yes than you may also need to add the alarm service for that event date.

Comment: It was intented that the app would have some sort of alarm on that date. But first off i need to create a function in which the user can make an event for the certain date, maybe with some checkbox options.